# Azure Data lake port connection

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

We are working on a POC to load data from various datasources to Azure Data lake Gen2 using Azure Data Factory. Is there any default port that we can use in ADF to connect to ADL? Please let me know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default port to connect to ADL or blob storage is 443. If your destination/sink is sql server, then the default port is 1433.

Doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime#ports-and-firewall

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Thank you so much Martin